# Why my display is black when my display card is enabled?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, graphics

I am running Windows 10 and today there suddenly was a glitch on my screen and everything became distorted.

I restarted the PC via power cable and upon coming back up I see only a black. If I boot to safe mode I can disable the display card and login to Windows again but while the card is enabled I cannot see anything but black.

I am connected through an HDMI port.

What do you think I should do to get my graphics card back?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is with the graphics card, but rather with the monitor.
When the card is enabled, Windows apparently uses it, but nothing comes up on the
monitor.

You need to find the source of the problem by testing:

- Download and install the latest graphics driver from the website of the manufacturer
  of the graphics card.
  If this doesn't help, delete in Device Manager the graphics card device and reboot
  so Windows will discover it again and install its own driver.
- Try another monitor cable,
- Try another monitor,
- Try another graphics card.

These tests will tell you whether it's a cable problem, driver problem,
a monitor problem or truly a graphics card problem.

If you don't have all the required parts for testing, a repair-shop might be
able to help.

Comment: I used a remote desktop connection from my laptop and at the time I enable the card the screen turns off and my remote connection also disconnects. I believe this means the whole computer stops working and it is not just the monitor. Am I right?

Comment: Most likely you are right. I would be careful with enabling the card if it causes such a problem. The chances are that the problem is electrical in nature. Perhaps a short-circuit in the card, perhaps the PSU has weakened and cannot support enough current with the card on. A repair-shop might be more economical than buying one component after another.